# RequestWebData but only few lines, not complete page

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to retrieve only first few rows of data without requesting the whole page?
I need only few words from 5th row (looking at page source) of text.

Usually I am using this code:

```
  Dim URLres As String = RequestWebData("http://quotes.morningstar.com/stock/s?t=XOM")
        label1.Text = URLres
```

But in this case there are more then 1300 rows of text and I would like to avoid loading that amount of data for only few words.

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably be using their API: [http://www.morningstarcommodity.com/tools-apis](http://www.morningstarcommodity.com/tools-apis).

Comment: Would love to but don't know how, spent days extracting data, one info at the time.

Comment: Look around on the page I linked to: they give instructions. You may need to do more research to implement it.

Comment: Thanks, but already checked that page, nothing there that would help me, only info, besides my programing knowledge isn't sufficient enough for something like that (no tutorials...). Anyways I am trying to extract company name based on a ticker symbol. I could use YahooFinance API, but Company names are not complete and I would like to avoid accessing two websites for datarequest because of the speed of data retrieval. So if you could help me with that?